# Should File Replication Services be running?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs

I have a network with one Windows 2003 Small Business Server.  I get a journal wrap error after every reboot for the past week.  I've seen the instructions on how to fix this, but before I do I'd like to know if File Replication Services should even be running if there's only one server in the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one domain controller in your network, then yes you can turn off File Replication services (FRS).

If you have a primary domain controller and secondary domain controller or backup domain controller, then I would look at fixing FRS.

Answer (score 0):

This service runs by default in the case that you promoted another DC. Had you ever at any point had another DC in this network?

Comment: I've never had another DC in the network, seems to be on by default on a SBS2003 installation.